# Use Synology as NUT server for Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, ups, nut

I am trying to configure my Ubuntu Server (20.04) as a slave to my Synology NAS hooked up to my UPS, but I'm not sure how to complete the process and I haven't found much of anything in terms of documentation or tutorials. Here are the steps I have taken:

On Synology DSM:

1. Hooked Synology up to UPS via USB
2. Turn on UPS Server in DSM settings

[image]

3. Add my Linux server IP in "Permitted DiskStation devices" dialog.

[image]

On Linux Server:

1. Installed NUT `sudo apt-get install nut`
2. Modified /etc/nut/nut.conf to `mode=netclient`
3. Added to /etc/nut/upsmon.conf `MONITOR ups@192.168.0.102 UPSUSER MYPASS slave`

Finally, when I try to run `service nut-client restart`, I get the error:

> Job for nut-monitor.service failed because the control process exited with error code.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what further steps I need to take? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out finally. Very simple answer and oversight on my part. In step, three I forgot the "1" after my ups IP.

Corrected step:

3. Added to /etc/nut/upsmon.conf `MONITOR ups@192.168.0.102 1 UPSUSER MYPASS slave`